# WordPress Settings API - Sanitize Integer

Tags: settings-api, sanitization

I am sanitizing a text field input via a custom WordPress Setting API page like this...

```
public function current_issue_sanitize($input) {
    $sanitary_values = array();
    if ( isset( $input['episode'] ) ) {
        $sanitary_values['episode'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['episode'] );
    }

    return $sanitary_values;
}
```

This is working well but I am now trying to sanitize and integer, is there a sanitize_text_field equivalent for numbers?

Comment: Why can't you use `sanitize_text_field()` on integers? If you want to return the int part of the value, you can use `$sanitary_values['episode'] = ( int ) sanitize_text_field( $input['episode'] );`

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168315/sanitizing-integer-input-for-update-post-meta

Answer (score 1):

If the integer should be a positive number, you can use `absint()`.  See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/absint